# How can I create a individual "Projects" page in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

On my Jekyll powered website, I have a page where I list every project (inventions, experiments, etc) that I have ever worked on. Currently, each project listed exists only as a link to a relevant blog post. My question is, how do I create individual pages for each  project so that it each resides in its own subdirectory like so:

example.com/projects/project1

example.com/projects/project2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create a folder called projects another folder for each project1 and then put a copy of the index.html file in there.

what it sounds like is you want to use categories/tags to automate this process for you

this might help: http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/